# How to restrict a method to override to just one subclass only in java? is it possible?

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, overriding

Let's say I have a method run in my class A

```
class A {
  void run(){
  }
}
```

and I have another class B which is going to extend class A.

```
class B extends A {    
  void run() {
  }    
}
```

I want to restrict run method only upto class B. No further overriding should be allowed. is this possible ?

Comment: Please take the time to format the code in your question in future, and make it valid code rather than pseudo-code - `class`, not `Class` in this case. Now do you *also* want to prevent other subclasses of `A` from overriding `run`, or just subclasses of `B`?

Comment: just subclass of B should not override.

Comment: Then do what the duplicate or Mureinik suggest in their answers.

Answer (score 2):

You could make `B`'s method `final`, so extending classes wouldn't be able to override it:

```
class B extends A {
    @Override
    final void run() {
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to restrict run method at class A level only not at class B level.